# SVG viewbox always relative to it's size?

Tags: html, css, svg

A pretty simple example if I have this square SVG:

```
<svg class="svg-correct-symbol" viewBox="0 0 442.533 442.533"
    width="50px" height="50px">
```

And I change it to:

```
<svg class="svg-correct-symbol" viewBox="0 0 200 200"
        width="50px" height="50px">
```

I will see about a quarter of the image right? Because the width and height is halved of the `window(viewbox)` you are 'looking through' to view the SVG.

So the viewbox's number: 442.533 will always mean 100% of the images width/height.

How it this default viewbox number set? Is this viewbox size determined by how large the file is when you export it? I would like to have a viewBox of something more rounded like `viewBox="0 0 16 16"`.

With an already exported image I don't see a way to change it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no default `viewBox` number. It is defined at the time the svg image is created (manually or by using software, like illustrator). It has 4 co-ordinates `x y width height`. What makes it tricky is that these coordinates have nothing to do with the image dimension and, like you mentioned, it only defines the area you are "looking through".

You can set the `viewbox` to any values you want. But you will also need to `scale` the svg image accordingly to fit your new viewbox. Similarly, you might also need to `translate` / shift the images in the `x , y` axis to bring it to centre or to fit the frame / `viewbox`.

Check out svg [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) from the documentation. 
[This](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-transformation.html) tutorial might also be useful to understand svg transforms.

And in case you are using a software like illustrator, all you need to do is set the dimension of the artboard which defines the viewbox and then scale accordingly.

Comment: This explains so much. It's a shame this is never really explained that well in most SVG tutorials. Either that or it's suppose to be common sense but I don't work with illustrator all that much. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: IMO this answer is a little confusing.  The `viewBox` doesn't describe the "area you are looking through". The `width` and `height` attributes do that.  The `viewBox` describes the area of the document that can be seen throuigh the viewport defined by the `width` and `height`.

Comment: By the way ss there a way to set the scale manually after you have exported it from something like illustrator?

Comment: @Stephan-v it is possible to scale manually after exporting from illustrator. Also, 
https://sarasoueidan.com/demos/interactive-svg-coordinate-system/index.html this should be helpful

Comment: @PaulLeBeau the width and height just scales up and down the image but the acutual portion of the defined image which is visible in the viewport is defined by viewbox so it isn't wrong to say "the area you are looking through"

Comment: I strongly disagree.  Saying "area you are looking at" would be more accurate.  Things that are in the viewBox area are not always visible in the SVG.

Comment: Isn't things in the defined viewbox area, only supposed to be visible in the svg.